# Adding Exchange 2007 Account To Windows 10 Mail App Broke My Emails

Tags: email, windows-10, exchange-server-2007

I added my work email account to the Windows 10 Mail app. This is an Microsoft Exchange 2007 account with a self-signed security certificate.

After adding the account using advanced setup, the Mail app prompted me to fix the account and said the following:

> ## Untrusted certificate
>
> The certificate from mail.xxx.xxx is invalid
> This might indicate an attempt to trick you or steal your info We
> don't recommend that you connect to this server Do you want to connect
> anyway?

I clicked *Continue* (since I know the certificate is trusted).

When I synced the mail account, I got a User Account Control prompt from Exchange Active Sync Policy Manager Broker, which I accepted. Then a message saying:

> ## Are you sure you want to add, update or remove your mail account?
>
> This may also change certain security policies on your device,
> including password complexity requirements, sign-in requirements after
> a specific period of inactivity, and a limited number of sign-in
> attempts.

I clicked *Yes*.

This enabled the account to successfully sync and I can read all my emails. However, now I can't send or receive new emails on ANY app on ANY device. I have tried OWA and Apple Mail on my iPhone (which previously worked fine with this email account). I have tried emailing from an external email address to this address, but it was not received. When I attempt to send a new email from this address, it gets put into my Drafts folder. I also can't delete any of my drafts.

I can't seem to find any information about this problem. Can anyone help?

Removing the account from the Windows 10 Mail app doesn't restore functionality to the email account on other devices. I'm not bothered about using this email account in the app - I would just like to restore functionality to the email address.